# Copy Row Range Dynamically Based on Contents of the same row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Want to copy row range based on its content and paste in below rows based in flag value in column. For example.

In range  B1:G1 , iF `B1 = TEST`, move next until that row value is not equal to TEST. For example let say B1,C1 and D1 are equal to TEST and starting from E1 is not equal to TEST(in short we need to check first not equal to TEST value in row `B1:G1` and start copy from that address but from next row till end), then copy `E2:G2` ( not E1:G1 as this is the condition row) and paste in below rows say `E3:G10`.

While pasting in`E3:G10`, it needs to check values in  A3 : Last row in A, lets if `A3 = X` then paste above logic to `E3:G3`, next if `A4 = Y` then skip, next if `A5 = X` , then paste above logic to `E5:G5.....and so on`.

In short we need first identify first <> TEST member in range `B1:G1` and copy range from that column but from below row and paste in all below rows skipping few based on flag seating in column A.

Below code is working but it clearing the contents of the skipped rows which we don't want. The new code should work for A3 to last row in column A.

```
Sub CopyOnCondition1()    
     Dim sh1 As Worksheet, c As Range    
     Set sh1 = Worksheets("SheetNameHere") 'change the sheetname

     For Each cel In sh1.Range("I11:T11")    
        If Not cel.Value = "TEST" Then    
            sh1.Range(Cells(12, cel.Column), Cells(12, 20)).Copy
            sh1.Range(Cells(13, cel.Column), Cells(24, 20)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas    
        End If    
     Next

     For Each cel In sh1.Range("H13:H24")    
        If cel.Value = "Y" Then sh1.Range("I" & cel.Row & ":T" & cel.Row).ClearContents    
     Next        
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the Screen shots of Before And After ? And what do you mean by clearing the Contents, if there wasn't anything already ? Also, make sure that this the full question that you want the answer to, changing the Question again and again  like last time isn't accepted.

Comment: Hi Mikku..There will be some formula seating in those rows where H(i) = Y hence the pseudo code will be as below :

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
Sub CopyOnCondition1()
     Dim sh1 As Worksheet, c As Range
     Set sh1 = Worksheets("SheetNameHere") 'change the sheetname
     Dim cl As Range
     Dim cel As Range

     For Each cel In sh1.Range("I11:T11")
        If Not cel.Value = "TEST" Then

            sh1.Range(Cells(12, cel.Column), Cells(12, 20)).Copy
            For Each cl In sh1.Range(Cells(13, cel.Column), Cells(24, cel.Column))
                  If Not sh1.Cells(cl.row, 8).Value = "Y" Then cl.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            Next
            Exit For
        End If

     Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Its working but only for fixed value of column H..Values will start from H13 but the the code should work from last row in column H.

Comment: Hi Mikku..well the code which you recommended is checking each value in range I11:T11, but the actual scenario is when it encounters first <> TEST member in range I11:T11, it should stop that search ahead. For example if the first <>  TEST member encoutered at N11, it should simple copy range N12:T12 and start pasting from N13:T13 and so on till the last row of column H starting H13 where H(i) <> Y.

Comment: Hi @NJB ... That was merely an addition of `Exit For` which I have done in the answer now.  So it will stop the loop after 1st `Test` is found

Comment: Hi @Mikku its not working...in fact nothing is working after this change.

Comment: Oh Sorry .. I added the condition in Wrong Place. It should have been inside If condition. @NJB

Comment: @NJB .. You can thank me by accepting and Upvoting the Answer :)

Comment: @NJB .. No you didn't accept and Upvote the Answer. Tick the sign with the Answer above and click the Upwards arrow to upvote. Maybe you can go back and do that on the previous questions also. !!